# Rotate Image to tilt down

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to add to my translate animation a rotate animation that tilts the left corner down 2 degrees and will be able to stay that way also at the end of the translate. Any idea?

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<!-- Move Two -->
<translate
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fromXDelta="-350"
    android:toXDelta="-700" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillEnabled="true"
     android:fillAfter="true">
     <rotate
         android:fromDegrees="0"
         android:toDegrees="2"
         android:duration="1000"/>
     <translate
         android:fromXDelta="0"
         android:toXDelta="-100" 
         android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Change value of translate tag according to your views position

add this animation to your view by AnimationUtils.loadAnimation() method